# How to find a corresponding value in a table in Matlab

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, I am given a table with two columns. Now I want to find the corresponding value of the left column to the maximum value of the right column:

```
P1_sat = P1(ismember(P2,max(P2)))
```

This works, however, the maximum is identical at 3 values of the left column, P1. These 3 values are right next to each other. So I want to consider the mid value. Is there a "consider the mid value" - command?

Comment: just solved it, sorry, this is really easy, just add the line {P1_sat = sum(P1_sat,1) / length(P1_sat) }

Comment: Why don't you turn that comment into a proper answer? This is [actively encouraged here on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), and you'll gain some repuration in the process!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following code line will complete my goal:

```
 P1_sat = sum(P1_sat,1) / length(P1_sat)
```

The three different values of P1, whose corresponding value of P2 is the maximum of P2, are added and then divided by 3. This gives the average value, which is also the mid point.